# Problem with trailing zeros after converting a pandas column to astype(str)

Tags: python, pandas

When I use print, without conversion, I got this format:

```
print(movusumodcir['FUNCAO'])
```

[image: Number format, without zeros]

Then I convert to string, try to remove trailing zeros and print again:

```
movusumodcir["FUNCAO"] = movusumodcir["FUNCAO"].astype(str)
movusumodcir["FUNCAO"]= movusumodcir["FUNCAO"].str.replace('.0', '')
print(movusumodcir['FU[![pY][1]][1]NCAO'])
```

Then I got this:

[image: Error]

What's wrong? I just want to remove trailing zeros..

Comment: ``.replace('.0', regex = False)``, by default replace assumes the passed-in pattern as regex.

Comment: I didn't know about it! Thanks

Comment: An alternative was:movusumodcir["FUNCAO"]= movusumodcir["FUNCAO"].str.strip(".0")

Answer (score 1):

```
movusumodcir["FUNCAO"] = movusumodcir["FUNCAO"].astype(np.str)
```

in place of `movusumodcir["FUNCAO"] = movusumodcir["FUNCAO"].astype(str)`